# Is the space isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

$\mathcal{P}_5$ and $\mathbb{R}^5$.

So $\mathbb{R}^5$ has a dimension of 5, but how do you determine the dimensions of $\mathcal{P}_5$?

Any element of $\mathcal{P}_5$ is of the form $a+bx+cx^2+...+fx^5$.

They are only isomorphic if they have the same dimension.

Additionally my book says $M_{2\times 3}$ & $\mathbb{R}^6$ are isomorphic but how can that be when $\mathbb{R}^6$ has a dimension of 6 when $M_{2\times 3} $ has a dimension of 1 because that is the number of free variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $P_5$ is likely to be the vector space of polynomials of degree **less than** $5$.  If this is correct, then
  \begin{align*}
  P_5 &= \{a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4:a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{R}\} \\
   &= \mathrm{span}\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}
  \end{align*}
  so has dimension $5$, and is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^5$.
- $M(2,3)$ is likely to be the vector space of $2 \times 3$ matrices with real entries, i.e.,
  \begin{align*}
  M(2,3) &= \left\{\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ \end{bmatrix} :a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{R} \right\} \\
   &= \mathrm{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right\}
  \end{align*}
  so has dimension $6$, and is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Comment: Can you explain how you find the dimensions, I don't think I understand it. For example what would the dimension of M(3X3)

Comment: The dimension is the number of basis elements.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I thought the dimension is the number of free variables.

Comment: In some sense that's true: to illustrate, if $\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\}$ is a basis of a vector space (which has dimension $3$, since it has a basis of size $3$) then the vector space is equal to $\{a\mathbf{u}+b\mathbf{v}+c\mathbf{w}:a,b,c \in \mathbb{F}\}$, so we have $3$ free variables $a,b,c$.  But it's not how dimension is defined: it's defined as the number of vectors in a basis.

Answer (score 1):

- The dimension of a vector space is the number of elements in any basis for that space, where a basis is any set of elements in the space such that any element in the space can be written as a linear combination of the basis elements.

  Considering $P_5$ as you have it, the set of all polynomials of degree 5 or less, the set {1, $x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5$} is a basis for that vector space, as any polynomial of degree 5 or less can be written as a linear combination of those vectore, i.e, $a*(1)+b*x+c*x^2+d*x^3+f*x^4+g*x^5$ for scalars a, b c, d, f, and g. The number of elements in this basis is 6, so here $P_5$ has dimension 6 and so is *not* isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^5}$, which has dimension 5. If, however, as Rebecca mentions, $P_5$ refers to polynomials of degree strictly *less* than 5, then a basis for this space would be {$1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4$} and, containing 5 elements in this basis, $P_5$ would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^5}$.
- $M_{2 \times 3}$ is the set of all (2$\times$3) matrices. To determine its dimension, we need to construct a basis for it, and then count the number of elements in this basis. Recall that a basis is a linearly independent set that spans the vector space. We need to find a set of (2$\times$3) matrices such that any (2$\times$3) matrix can be written as a linear combination of these matrices. The set $$
          \left\{
          \begin{pmatrix}
          1 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & 0 \\
          \end{pmatrix}, 
          \begin{pmatrix}
          0 & 1 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & 0 \\
          \end{pmatrix},
          \begin{pmatrix}
          0 & 0 & 1 \\
          0 & 0 & 0 \\
          \end{pmatrix},
          \begin{pmatrix}
          0 & 0 & 0 \\
          1 & 0 & 0 \\
          \end{pmatrix},
          \begin{pmatrix}
          0 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & 1 & 0 \\
          \end{pmatrix},
          \begin{pmatrix}
          0 & 0 & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & 1 \\
          \end{pmatrix},
         \right\}
  $$

  ought to do the trick, we can write any matrix
  $$
         \begin{pmatrix}
          a & b & c \\
          d & f & g \\
          \end{pmatrix}
  $$

  in the form

$$
a\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
+ b\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
+ c\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
+ d\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
+ f\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
+ g\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
    hence, a linear combination of the vectors in our set, so the set spans the space. Now we check that the set is linearly independent. It most certainly is. Consider the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
$. Any linear combination of the other matrices will be of the form
$
       \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & b & c \\
        d & f & g \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$, with a zero in the 1,1th position, hence, the matrix cannot be written as a linear combination of the other matrices. The same follows for every matrix in this set. So the set is a basis for the space. Then we count the number of elements in this set. There are precisely 6 of them. So the space has dimension 6.

So, since we have shown that the space is of dimension 6, it follows that the space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^6}$.